# Output float with different number of decimals each time

Tags: java, string, output, decimal, precision

I am trying to resolve this for quite some time. What I need is a script as simple as possible that takes float 'x' and int 'n' and then outputs 'x' with 'n' number of decimals. It could be somethng like:

```
float x = 111.1111f;    
int n = 2;

System.out.printf("%{n}f", x);
```

(Outputs: '111.11')

What I am mainly looking for is some kind of a formatting tool allowing you to use variables inside of string declarations. Is there a way as simple as this to make it work? If not, what is the most simple solution of my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the 'obvious'.....

```
System.out.printf("%." + n + "f", x);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, I only had to add a missing dot.

System.out.printf(".%" + n + "f", x);

Comment: No problem, added dot for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use decimal formatter to achieve this

```
        int n = 2;
        float x = 111.1111f;  
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(n);
        System.out.println(df.format(x));
```